# Corrupt npm error when building my first Cordova App

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, tools-for-apache-cordova

This is my first look into using Cordova with Visual Studio, I followed the Apache Cordova installation process and started to go through the first app example.  When I run the Ripple - Nexus function I get the following output/errro:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: WeatherApp, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Current package installation is corrupted. Will cleanup and do a fresh installation.
1>------ npm install error : error : spawn cmd ENOENT
1>  ------ Installing Cordova tools cordova@6.1.1 for project from npm. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>MDAVSCLI : [Error ------ npm install error : cordova@6.1.1]
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Build error: ------ npm install error: cordova@6.1.1
1>Build error : ------ npm install error : cordova@6.1.1
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have uninstalled the Cordova tools and reinstalled them, I uninstalled Android Studio (did not reinstall but reinstalled the Android SDK) and I've tried to reinstall the vs-tac via the command line.  Please help as I would very much like to work with these tools.

Thanks,
Alex

*Edit: I've added System32 to the path and reinstalled NodeJs and npm but now I get the following error:

------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few 
minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not 
responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. 
Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional 
licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any 
dependencies.
1>  ENOENT, no such file or directory ''
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : module.js:338

I've run npm install -g  in the command line, I have node version V5.12.0 and npm version 5.2.0.

Thanks - Alex

Comment: Please try adding `C:\Windows\System32\` to the path. If it doesn't work, please try reinstalling npm or nodeJS.

Comment: Where do I add the Path?  I've reinstalled npm a couple times, I will try reinstalling nodeJS.

Comment: Right Click `This PC`->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variable->Find the `path` variable in User Variables for <username> and add `C:\Windows\System32` to the variable.

Comment: Okay, now I've added the path and reinstalled NodeJS along with npm and I'm getting a different error, I will add to the original post.

Comment: Please try clearing cordova cache under Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Clear Cordova Cache.

Comment: @AlexMarten, did you manage to resolve this? I have the same error as the one in your edit. Clearing cordova cache does not help.

Comment: @potPan, I did mostly get this resolved, it was an issue with npm and NodeJS versions that are compatible with Cordova.  I'm not sure what I ended up with exactly but be sure to read through the Cordova install instructions to find out which versions are verified to work.  I've actually moved in another direction so I'm not currently using it but I hope this helps.